# Issue on re-render list when removing an item from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a lists for texts which user can delete and edit. but i got an issue when trying to implementing it, here's what my current development.

To create the list, i render elements by mapping the object using this function

```
function textContainer(e, color) {
    var textForm = `
        <form onsubmit="return false" class="form-inline my-2 text-form row" style="display:flex; justify-content:space-around;">
            <input class="col-9 form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" id="newText"
                placeholder="Name, Number etc">
            <button class="col-2 btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"
                onclick="addText(newText.value)">Add Text</button>
        </form>
    `;
    var textLayer = '';
    var id = 0;
    var iconColor = 'black';
    if (color != null) {
        iconColor = color
    }
    canvas._objects.map(object => {
        if (object.text != undefined) {
            console.log(object.fill)
            id += 1;
            textLayer = `
            <ul class="listTexts" style="padding :0;">
                <li id="text-`+ id + `" class="buttonLists">
                    <span>`+ id + `. ` + object.text + `</span>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="margin:0px 5px;" onclick="removeTextById(`+ id + `)"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            `;
        }
    });
    if (canvas._objects.length == 1) {
        $('.textContainer').append(textForm).html();
    } else if (e == 'removed') {
        $('.textContainer').append(textForm + textLayer).html();
    } else if (e == 'changed') {
        $('.listTexts').empty();
        $('.listTexts').append(textLayer).html();
    } else {
        $('.textContainer').append(textLayer).html();
    }
}
```

and removing the item based on their id like this

```
function removeTextById(id) {
    var array = canvas._objects.filter(function (el) {
        return el.text != null
    })
    canvas.remove(array[id - 1]);
    $('.textContainer').empty();
    textContainer('removed');
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

this is works well, if it's only contains 1 or 2 item on the list, i can delete any item. But when it contains more than 2, for example 3, it'll remove 2 `li` tag, if it's 4 it'll remove 3 `li` tag. I dont know what happen, but my objects is correct, it only deleting 1 item. You can see it in action here https://natestudio.my.id/3d-configurator on text tab.

anyone have any idea why is that happening?

EDIT

`canvas` in my app is fabricjs canvas, and `canvas._objects` return lists of object inside that canvas. I'll try to create a simple reproduce in a minute

EDIT 2

Here's a minimal reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/2758bskq/6/

Comment: Information is lacking *inside* the question. For instance, we cannot know what `canvas.remove` will do, and whether it has no bugs (We should not have to look at an external site for that). Please provide enough information/code in the question for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, i'll try to create a minimal reproduce in a minute

Comment: i've created a minimal reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the removal action, the list is displayed here:

```
else if (e == 'removed') {
    $('.textContainer').append(textForm + textLayer).html();
```

Before this executes, `$('.textContainer')` is empty. As `textLayer` contains *one* item only (see the loop above it), at most one item will be displayed after a removal.

So one problem is the collection of `textLayer`: it should collect all relevant items, not just the last one. So replace:

```
textLayer =
```

with:

```
textLayer +=
```

But this will have bad consequences for other scenarios (addition, ...etc). To avoid that, just rebuild the list *always*.

So replace `if (canvas._objects.length == 1) {` and the whole `if..else` structure that follows it with just:

```
$('.textContainer').empty().append(textForm + textLayer);
```

This will fix the problem you mentioned.

Snippet (with canvas size reduced, so to focus on the list):

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  centeredScaling: true,
});

function addText(text) {
  if (text != '') {
    jerseyName = new fabric.IText(text, {
      fontSize: 25,
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      left: 100,
      top: 280,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      selectable: true
    });
    canvas.add(jerseyName);
    canvas.setActiveObject(jerseyName);
    textContainer();
    $('.text-form').each(function() {
      this.reset();
    });
  }
}

function textContainer() {
  var textForm = `
    <form onsubmit="return false" class="form-inline my-2 text-form row" style="display:flex; justify-content:space-around;">
      <input class="col-9 form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" id="newText"
        placeholder="Name, Number etc">
      <button class="col-2 btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"
        onclick="addText(newText.value)">Add Text</button>
    </form>
  `;
  var textLayer = '';
  var id = 0;
  canvas._objects.map(object => {
    if (object.text != undefined) {
      id += 1;
      textLayer += `
      <ul class="listTexts" style="padding :0;">
        <li id="text-` + id + `" class="buttonLists">
          <span>` + id + `. ` + object.text + `</span>
          <div>
            <button  onclick="removeTextById(` + id + `)">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      `;
    }
  });
  $('.textContainer').empty().append(textForm + textLayer);
}

function removeTextById(id) {
  var array = canvas._objects.filter(function(el) {
    return el.text != null
  })
  canvas.remove(array[id - 1]);
  textContainer();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

textContainer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" height="10" width="400"></canvas>

<div class="tab-pane p-3 textContainer" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="two-tab">
</div>
```

Comment: i've tried using `textLayer +=` but doesn't give me the result that i wanted, `$('.textContainer').empty().append(textForm + textLayer);` is what i really need, thanks !

Comment: OK, if it works for you, that is important. I don't really see how it would work without `+=` because if your list has 3 or more elements, and you then delete one item, you will end up with one element (represented by `textLayer`) after a delete. I added a snippet to my answer.

Comment: i added that, but i'm just saying that i've tried that but it doesn't work, so what i need now is `$('.textContainer').empty().append(textForm + textLayer);`. Thanks that willl be helpful for someone in the future